# How to get two actor system running in docker to form a cluster

Tags: docker, akka, docker-network, akka-cluster

I am working my way to understanding Akka and Akka clustering.

So far so good I have been able to create two actor system and have them form a cluster when I start each separately in two different console (i.e. running each in its own jvm).

The configuration looks like this:

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = cluster
    deployment {
      /workRouter {
        router = round-robin-group
        routees.paths = ["/user/worker"]
        cluster {
          enabled = on
          allow-local-routees = on
         }
      }
    }
  }
  remote {
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = ${clustering.host-ip} // this is over riden in the non-seed cluster
      port = ${clustering.host-port}
    }
  }
  cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
     "akka.tcp://"${clustering.name}"@"${clustering.router-seed-ip}":"${clustering.router-seed-port}
   ]
  }
}

# variables
clustering {

  host-ip = "127.0.0.1"
  host-ip = ${?HOST_IP}

  host-port = 2551
  host-port = ${?HOST_PORT}

  router-seed-ip = "127.0.0.1"
  router-seed-ip = ${?ROUTER_CLUSTER_SEED_IP}

  router-seed-port = 2551
  router-seed-port = ${?ROUTER_CLUSTER_SEED_PORT}

  name = "ExperimentCluster"

}
```

Basically the seed node runs on 127.0.0.1:2551 and the non seed node runs on 127.0.0.1:2553

So up next, I will like to run each of them in a docker container and have them still form a cluster. They actor system runs, but the non seed seems unable to join the seed node

This is the way I start the seed node:

`docker run -p=2551:2551 --rm seedroute:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT`

and this is the way I started the non seed node:

`docker run -p=2551:2551 --rm workerroute:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT`

But in the logs of the non seed node, I see the following:

```
[WARN] [11/24/2019 09:48:54.993] [ExperimentCluster-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ExperimentCluster)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ExperimentCluster@127.0.0.1:2553] - Couldn't join seed nodes after [22] attempts, will try again. seed-nodes=[akka.tcp://ExperimentCluster@127.0.0.1:2551]
```

This was not the case when I ran the node on seperate JVM, which points to the fact that this is related to docker and networking. I thought passing the `-p` flag and exposing the ports would work but apparently there is more about the networking aspect I do not understand yet.

I am not using *docker-compose* or *docker swarm* yet. I will finally use one of these, but since this is a learning exercise, I want to get the pieces and fundamentals right as I move up the tools.

So does anyone knows how to get this working? Basically start two Akka nodes, manually in a docker container and have them be able to communicate and form a cluster with each other.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is exactly the reason you would use Docker Compose - so each container may be deployed into a network in which they are able to communicate with each other.

You can do this manually by manually creating a network and adding containers to it as per https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/
but I'm not sure this has much learning utility apart from simply moving on to basic `compose` experimentation.

If you don't want to do this, you can, of course, use `--net=host` to expose the containers to the host network and simply let them communicate directly - this, however, negates a lot of the benefits of container networking in the first place - the ability to keep the network isolated and only to bridge/expose port entry points you really need to be externally accessible.

Another alternative would be to use multiple compose files for each container you wish to insert into the network at some point, and have these join into an existing named network, as per https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network.